# Selenium looking for id="form_error"

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Hello So i am logging into a website and am trying to login but if sometimes there is an authentication failure and the browser pops up "Please Try Again" i go to the html and it is under an id="form_error"
so I am trying to right in my code if id in self.chrome = try again. this is python3 selenium

```
self.chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]", id="form_error")
            if id in self.chrome_browser.page_source:
                print("trying again" + random_code)
```

the error i am getting is:

```
TypeError: find_element_by_xpath() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
```

I am a bit confused because I gave the function the argument. Thanks in advance

Comment: why did i get negged

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
if "error" in self.chrome_browser.page_source:
                print("trying again" + random_code)
```

Comment: To other reviewers: this is the answer provided by the OP to solve his own solution.  It is not appropriate to **Recommend Deletion**.

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.

Comment: Also you should pay more attention to indentation with python